# Strange exception while using pip to install python packages after deleting rabbitmq in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, numpy, pip, rabbitmq

Good morining,
I was trying to install RabbitMQ in my Ubuntu18.04 but it was like brain surgery. I have decided to remove everything, but now when I try to install python packages with pip, the terminal return strange exceptions. I have similar problems when I try to compile a python script with visualStudio. I really appreciate your help. Stay tech!
These are the exceptions:

```
pip3 install numpy
Collecting numpy
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/pypi/simple/numpy/
```

Comment: Look for excessive URLs in `~/.pip/pip.conf` or `~/.config/pip/pip.conf`

Comment: You are a saint! I have canceled the url inside the pip.conf and it works!

Comment: Thank you. How can I increase your reputation?

Comment: I made an answer so you can upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excessive URL in `~/.pip/pip.conf` or `~/.config/pip/pip.conf`. Remove it and retry.